# Bagel monster eats bagels

Tags: markov-chains

Say I have 3 big bagels and 7 tiny bagels in a bag. Every minute, Bagel Monster randomly picks a bagel from the bag. If it's a tiny bagel, it's eaten; if it's a big bagel, it's cut into 2 pieces, where one half is eaten and the other half is put back into the bag as a tiny bagel. After how many minutes is it expected for the bag to have only tiny bagels left?

Comment: You should know by now that you first need to show your effort and where you are stuck, and also indicate the source of the problem, so please edit it in.

Comment: It should take about 10 minutes max to make a program which will take 1 second more to output you your desired number. That's because I don't think there will be a nice closed form for this. So, should we help you with the code instead?

Comment: If the question really is: when is the expected value of the number of big bagels zero for the first time, and not something like when does the expected value pass some small thresshold, then one can indeed give a closed form.

Comment: @a_student Sorry, I did not understand you. What is your suggested modification of this question? Am I understanding it right that you are leaning towards asymptotics?

Comment: per site guidelines, please share with us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of tiny bagels, $m$ - the number of big bagels at some time.

Let also $E_{n,m}$ - expected time to result (to moment, when $n=0$).

So
$$E_{0,m} = 0,\quad m=0,1,2,...10$$

Also from state $E_{n,m}$ we can move to $E_{n,m-1}$ with probability $\dfrac{m}{m+n}$ or to $E_{n-1,m+1}$ with probability $\dfrac{n}{m+n}$, so
$$E_{n,m} = \dfrac{m}{m+n}\left(E_{n,m-1} + 1 \right) + \dfrac{n}{m+n}\left(E_{n-1,m+1} + 1 \right)= \dfrac{m}{m+n}E_{n,m-1} + \dfrac{n}{m+n}E_{n-1,m+1} + 1$$

Using this conditions we can find $E_{1,m}$ for $ m=0,1,2,...10$:

$$E_{1,0} = \dfrac{0}{1}E_{1,-1} + \dfrac{1}{1}E_{0,1}+1 = 1$$

$$E_{1,m} = \dfrac{m}{m+1}E_{1,m-1} + \dfrac{1}{m+1}E_{0,m+1} + 1 = \dfrac{m}{m+1}E_{1,m-1} + 1$$

We can use formula for $E_{1,m-1}$:

$$E_{1,m} = \dfrac{m}{m+1}\left(\dfrac{m-1}{m}E_{1,m-2} + \dfrac{1}{m}E_{0,m} + 1\right) + 1 = \dfrac{m-1}{m+1}E_{1,m-2} + 1 + \dfrac{m}{m+1}$$

If we continue this process as result we have:

$$E_{1,m} = \dfrac{1}{m+1}E_{1,0} + \dfrac{1}{m+1}\sum_{i=2}^{m+1}i = \dfrac{1}{m+1}\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} = \dfrac{m+2}{2} = 1 + \dfrac{m}{2}$$

Now we can find $E_{2,m}$ for $ m=0,1,2,...9$ the same as with $E_{1,m}$:

$$E_{2,0} = \dfrac{0}{2}E_{2,-1} + \dfrac{2}{2}E_{1,1}+1 = 0 + \dfrac{1+2}{2} +1 = \dfrac{5}{2}$$

$$E_{2,m} = \dfrac{m}{m+2}E_{2,m-1} + \dfrac{2}{m+2}E_{1,m+1}+1 = $$
$$= \dfrac{m}{m+2}E_{2,m-1} + \dfrac{2}{m+2}\dfrac{m+3}{2} + 1 = \dfrac{m}{m+2}E_{2,m-1} + \dfrac{1}{m+2} + 2$$

As result:

$$E_{2,m} = \dfrac{5}{2} + \dfrac{2}{3}m = \dfrac{15 + 4m}{6}$$

Finally we can find $E_{3,m}$ for $ m=0,1,2,...8$ the same as with $E_{2,m}$:

$$E_{3,0} = \dfrac{0}{3}E_{3,-1} + \dfrac{3}{3}E_{2,1}+1 = 0 + \dfrac{15 + 4}{6} +1 = \dfrac{25}{6}$$

$$E_{3,m} = \dfrac{25}{6} + \dfrac{3}{4}m = \dfrac{50 + 9m}{12}$$

The answer of our problem is $E_{3,7}$:

$$E_{3,10} = \dfrac{50 + 9\cdot7}{12}=\dfrac{113}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

**This is not meant to be an answer**
This is just a piece of code which calculates this expected value, don't take it as an answer! Take it as a tool to help yourself if you want to work on this problem.

The code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int args,char **argv){
    #define LOL {printf("LOL\n");return 1;}
    if(args!=3)LOL
    int B=atoi(argv[1]);
    int S=atoi(argv[2]);
    if((B<0)|(S<0)|((B==0)&(S==0))|(B>100)|(S>100))LOL
    float _f[(B+S+1)*(B+1)];
    #define f(x,y) _f[(x)*(B+S+1)+y]
    for(int i=0;i<=B+S;++i)f(0,i)=0;
    for(int j=1;j<=B;++j){
        f(j,0)=1+f(j-1,1);
        for(int i=1;i+j<=B+S;++i)
            f(j,i)=1+(f(j,i-1)*i+f(j-1,i+1)*j)/(float)(i+j);
    }
    printf("%f\n",f(B,S));
    return 0;
}
```

The output for `3 7` is $\frac{113}{12}$.

Comment: The word code is not countable in this context. It is incorrect to say "a code".

Comment: @JohnDouma A source code? What do you suggest then? And, in what context is code a countable word?

Comment: This is code or this is some code is what I would have said. For example, if someone reviewed your code and thought that it could be simpler they might say "use less code" but they wouldn't say "use fewer code" which would be the case if the word code was countable.

Comment: @JohnDouma Aaaa, I see. Thanks. I was always thinking that code can also mean a file containing the code. That is countable then. Or, abstractly, a complete code, not necessarily inside a file, would also be "a code" in my words. I'll fix now...

Comment: @donaastor it is not advisable to assist an OP who makes no observable effort to answer questions themselves